Error while installing mkdocs plugin `mkdocs-include-markdown-plugin` using pip requirements.txt
We are trying to use mkdocs plugin mkdocs-include-markdown-plugin (source, pip package) to reuse some of the text contents in our documentation. Our CI/CD pipeline is trying to install this plugin using the below command:
pip install --require-hashes -r docs/requirements.txt

I have added the line below in the requirements.txt
mkdocs-include-markdown-plugin==6.0.5 --hash=sha256:db41aa1937a618afa3497616f457d4e51d9123b13b2034bb15505ff9ce061f86

Problem:
We run into ERROR below:
Collecting wcmatch<9,>=8 (from mkdocs-include-markdown-plugin==6.0.5->-r docs/requirements.txt (line 10))
ERROR: In --require-hashes mode, all requirements must have their versions pinned with ==. These do not:
    wcmatch<9,>=8 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/06/73f17a8c322de938809f570e7bb09f1345fc9821b8fbe37f0f785d403475/wcmatch-8.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (from mkdocs-include-markdown-plugin==6.0.5->-r docs/requirements.txt (line 10))

To me, it seems that wcmatch is a transitive dependency and the way it's version is mentioned in the source of the mkdocs-include-markdown-plugin plugin is causing the problem.
But I might be wrong.

What could be the issue here
How can it be fixed?

